# Slow mysql query, join on huge table, not using indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT archive.id, archive.file, archive.create_timestamp, archive.spent 
FROM archive LEFT JOIN submissions ON archive.id = submissions.id
WHERE submissions.id is NULL 
AND archive.file is not NULL 
AND archive.create_timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 month) 
AND spent = 0 
ORDER BY archive.create_timestamp ASC LIMIT 10000
```

EXPLAIN result:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                  | key              | key_len | ref                                        | rows      | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | archive            | range  | create_timestamp,file_in       | create_timestamp | 4       | NULL                                       | 111288502 | Using where                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | submissions        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY          | 4       | production.archive.id                      |         1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

I've tried hinting use of indexes for archive table with:

```
USE INDEX (create_timestamp,file_in)
```

Archive table is huge, ~150mil records.

Any help with speeding up this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very nice, thanks, query is not using indexes - not my choice - as you would have figured out if you took time to look at explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a composite index.  For this query:

```
create index archive_file_spent_createts on archive(file, spent, createtimestamp);
```

In such an index, you want the `where` conditions with `=` to come first, followed by up to one column with an inequality.  In this case, I'm not sure if MySQL will use the index for the `order by`.

This assumes that the `where` conditions do, indeed, significantly reduce the size of the data.

Comment: Thanks! They do in fact reduce size to ~20mil. Idea was to go though records that match this criteria and do some processing - but split with the use of limit.

If it's still slow, I guess I should find another way to split the data, by introducing another where ?